# GET request with HTTP to port 80 results in connection reset or no response from server

Tags: apache, http, port, centos6

I have a strange issue that the SSL connection for port 443 on my server is working fine, but when I look for the HTTP variant of my server it gives me the 'Site can't be reached connection was reset' error.

I have the following rules in my iptables:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

The apache access_log does show an incomming request when requesting the site via HTTP, and the error_log does not show any errors

In my httpd.conf file I have:

```
Listen 80
```

My intention was to let all traffic go via HTTPS, so I have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

However, it does not matter if I place this last block here or comment it - the server is not reachable via HTTP. I am on CentOS 6.7.

Edit:

When I do `curl http://example.com`, it returns `cURL (52) Empty reply from server`

However, when I check the apache http access_log for that cURL request, it returns

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx - - [02/Jun/2016:22:46:06 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 314 "-"
```

Which indicates that I should have received a HTTP response status 302 Found code as intended. However, I received nothing.

Any help or suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Apparantly there was another firewall on a higher level than the one on my server that was causing the problems.